# Duda con código en c++, registro de temperaturas

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo con C++ y mi profesor de programación me asigno un proyecto que no se muy bien como hacer y el no explica tampoco. Este es el enunciado:
Proyecto.
Registro de temperaturas:
*menú*

1. Crear archivo actual de n temperaturas
2. Mostrar promedios de Archivo actual
3. Mostrar promedio de Archivo histórico
4. Promedio total de ambos archivos
5. Mostrar archivo histórico
6. Mostrar Archivo actual
7. salir

También el programa, cuando se vaya a agregar temperaturas por segunda vez debe decir un mensaje como "Tienes temperaturas sin guardar, estas pasaran al archivo histórico", y hacer el traspaso de las temperaturas del archivo actual al archivo histórico, pero no encuentro forma de hacerlo. Solamente llevo la opción uno del código la cual sería esta.

Si pudieran ayudarme estaría muy agradecido ya que es para el 31 de enero y es la nota más importante de la materia.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void tempeA ();
string contenido;
int op, tem, n;

float temperatura [100] ;

int main(){

tempeA ();
system("pause");
return 0;
}

void tempeA () {

ofstream archivoActual;

archivoActual.open("TemperaturaAC.txt",ios::app);
if(archivoActual.fail()){
cout<<"Error desconocido a la hora de abrir/crear el archivo";
exit(1);

}

do{

cout<<"\t Bienvenido al programa para el Guardado de Temperaturas"<<endl;

cout<<"\n Menu de opciones"<<endl;

cout<<"\n 1. Crear archivo e ingresar temperaturas"<<endl;

cout<<"\n 2. Promedio Historico"<<endl;

cout<<"\n 3. Promedio Actual"<<endl;

cout<<"\n 4. Promedio Actual Más Promedio Historico"<<endl;

cout<<"\n 5. Mostrar archivo historico"<<endl;

cout<<"\n 6. Mostrar Archivo Actual"<<endl;

cout<<"\n 7. Salir"<<endl;


cout<<"\n Por favor presione el numero con la opcion a elegir: "<<endl;

cin>>op;

switch (op){

case 1: cout<<"Ingrese la cantidad de temperaturas que se van a ingresar: "<<endl;
cin>>n;

for (int i=0; i<n; i++){

cout<<"Digite la temperatura a registrar: "<<endl;

cin>>temperatura[i];
archivoActual<<temperatura[i]<<endl;
} break;

}


} while (op>0 && op<5); //menu

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido ¿Entonces necesitas ayuda con todo excepto el punto 1? Solo respondemos preguntas acotadas, así que en ese caso no podemos ayudarte. Lo suyo sería una tutoría, cosa que no hacemos.

Comment: Como sugerencia y parte de las buenas prácticas de código limpio, crea funciones para las diferentes tareas. Una para crear el archivo, otra para ver el promedio histórico, otra para el actual y así. De lo contrario el código será un desastre difícil de leer y odiarás tu vida conforme avances.

Comment: Muchas gracias, en realidad solo necesitaba saber como realizar el traspaso de datos de un archivo a otro pero muchas gracias, y gracias por el consejo también voy a aplicarlo

Comment: Si tienes dudas puntuales, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Lo hare, muchas gracias